# Asp-page doesn't link to next view

Tags: asp.net

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKsYn.png)

[web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGwNW.png)

Why "asp-page" doesn't link to view Create? When I changed to <.a href="/Movies/Create">Create New<./a> it does.

Comment: Post the *code*, not screenshots of some of the code. If you get an error post the error

Comment: because it is not a page, you need controller and action.

Comment: @Sehakx the OP forgot to mention it's an ASP.NET Core application. And forgot to post the code for those pages too

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but I posted screenshot becouse I hope my SolutionExplorer window in the photo is helpful to solve this problem.

Comment: Read [Scaffolded Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/page?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to see how those pages should be created.

Comment: @JaredPeto it's not. In fact, people are forced to guess even the .NET version you use - ASP.NET MVC? Web API? ASP.NET Core? With Razor Pages or not?

Answer (score 1):

Must call the `action` on movies `controller`

```
<a asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Create">Create new</a>
```